# How To handle I/O error: failed to connect to /10.0.2.2 (port 8080): connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out) inside Async Task

Tags: android

I am calling a rest web service during Login using Rest Template. The Server hosting the service was not active. I tried to Login, it took some time and then throws an exception connect failed.

I want to set a timer, for ex:- 30 seconds. If the AsyncTask's `doInBackground()` do not complete execution, I want to cancel it and show a message, server not available try again later.

Now, I used **CountDownTimer** and I called `cancel()` to achieve this, I almost achieved it but I am getting a feeling that something is wrong. Because after timeout the `doInBackground()` does not stop,it continues execution in background and printed a log message set inside the `postExecute()`.

Can Anyone suggest a way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

When configuring `RestTemplate`, you can configure `timeout`

```
// If using OkHttp, use OkHttpRequestFactory
HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory clientHttpRequestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
clientHttpRequestFactory.setConnectTimeout(20000);
clientHttpRequestFactory.setReadTimeout(20000);
RestTemplate testTemplate = new RestTemplate(clientHttpRequestFactory);
```

And you can `try/catch` exceptions when making network calls to show message to user.